# Can't display all products

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, spree

i'm working on a Rails application with Spree Commerce.

I'm trying to display **all products** in a **taxon** cause i'm using them not as category but as some kind of registry.

So, i'm editing /app/views/spree/taxons/show.html.erb. Especifically this line:

```
<%= render partial: 'spree/shared/products', locals: { products: @products, taxon: @taxon } %>
```

Changing it for:

```
<%= render :partial => 'spree/shared/products', :locals => { :products => @products } %>
```

But it still says "No products found". But in my index they are showed.

So, How can I properly show all products?

Thanks in advance.

```
ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-linux]
Rails 4.2.5
Spree 3.0.4
```

As requested:

1) This is the show from products

```
<% @body_id = 'product-details' %>

<% cache [I18n.locale, current_currency, @product, @product.possible_promotions] do %>
  <div data-hook="product_show" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Product">
    <div class="col-md-4" data-hook="product_left_part">
      <div data-hook="product_left_part_wrap">
        <div id="product-images" data-hook="product_images">
          <div id="main-image" class="panel panel-default" data-hook>
            <div class="panel-body text-center">
              <%= render :partial => 'image' %>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="thumbnails" data-hook>
            <%= render :partial => 'thumbnails' %>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div data-hook="product_properties">
          <%= render :partial => 'properties' %>
        </div>

        <div data-hook="promotions">
          <%= render :partial => 'promotions' %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-8" data-hook="product_right_part">
      <div data-hook="product_right_part_wrap">
        <div id="product-description" data-hook="product_description">
          <h1 class="product-title" itemprop="name"><%= @product.name %></h1>

          <div class="well" itemprop="description" data-hook="description">
            <%= product_description(@product) rescue Spree.t(:product_has_no_description) %>
          </div>

          <div id="cart-form" data-hook="cart_form">
            <%= render :partial => 'cart_form' %>
          </div>
        </div>

        <%= render :partial => 'taxons' %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

2) Show from taxons

```
<h1 class="taxon-title"><%= @taxon.name %></h1>

<% content_for :sidebar do %>
  <div data-hook="taxon_sidebar_navigation">
    <%= render partial: 'spree/shared/taxonomies' %>
    <%= render partial: 'spree/shared/filters' if @taxon.leaf? %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<div data-hook="taxon_products">
  <%= render partial: 'spree/shared/products', locals: { products: @products, taxon: @taxon } %>
</div>

<% unless params[:keywords].present? %>
  <div data-hook="taxon_children">
    <% cache [I18n.locale, @taxon] do %>
      <%= render partial: 'taxon', collection: @taxon.children %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

3) This is how I render in my index

```
<div data-hook="homepage_products">
  <% cache(cache_key_for_products) do %>
    <%= render :partial => 'spree/shared/products', :locals => { :products => @products } %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

4) _products.html.erb

```
<%
  paginated_products = @searcher.retrieve_products if params.key?(:keywords)
  paginated_products ||= products
%>

<% content_for :head do %>
  <% if paginated_products.respond_to?(:num_pages) %>
    <%= rel_next_prev_link_tags paginated_products %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>

<div data-hook="products_search_results_heading">
  <% if products.empty? %>
    <div data-hook="products_search_results_heading_no_results_found">
      <%= Spree.t(:no_products_found) %>
    </div>
  <% elsif params.key?(:keywords) %>
    <div data-hook="products_search_results_heading_results_found">
      <h6 class="search-results-title"><%= Spree.t(:search_results, keywords: h(params[:keywords])) %></h6>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>

<% if products.any? %>
  <div id="products" class="row" data-hook>
    <% products.each do |product| %>
      <% url = spree.product_url(product, taxon_id: @taxon.try(:id)) %>
      <div id="product_<%= product.id %>" class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 product-list-item" data-hook="products_list_item" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Product">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <% cache(@taxon.present? ? [I18n.locale, current_currency, @taxon, product] : [I18n.locale, current_currency, product]) do %>
            <div class="panel-body text-center product-body">
              <%= link_to small_image(product, itemprop: "image"), url, itemprop: 'url' %><br/>
              <%= link_to truncate(product.name, length: 50), url, class: 'info', itemprop: "name", title: product.name %>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer text-center">
              <span itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Offer">
                <span class="price selling lead" itemprop="price"><%= display_price(product) %></span>
              </span>
            </div>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    <% reset_cycle("classes") %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<% if paginated_products.respond_to?(:num_pages) %>
  <%= paginate paginated_products, theme: 'twitter-bootstrap-3' %>
<% end %>
```

Controller index:

```
module Spree
  class HomeController < Spree::StoreController
    helper 'spree/products'
    respond_to :html

    def index
      @searcher = build_searcher(params.merge(include_images: true))
      @products = @searcher.retrieve_products
      @taxonomies = Spree::Taxonomy.includes(root: :children)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: can you display the controller method related to your index page (where the products exists)  ?

Comment: Just added it. At the bottom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `spree/frontend/app/controllers/spree/taxons_controller.rb`

make the `show` method look like this

```
    def show
      @taxon = Taxon.friendly.find(params[:id])
      return unless @taxon

      @searcher = build_searcher(params.merge(include_images: true))
      @products = @searcher.retrieve_products
      @taxonomies = Spree::Taxonomy.includes(root: :children)
    end
```

Comment: `@searcher =build_searcher(build_searcher(params.merge(include_images: true)))`

Answer (score 0):

First of, your file should be called `_products.html.erb`.

> But it still says "No products found"

Second, could you please show us this file?

> But in my index they are showed.

Could you also show us how you render your products in your index?

EDIT: It seems like in `Taxons#show`, the `@products` instance variable is not set. Check if you set it in the show action in your `TaxonsController`.

Comment: Do you have a file called `_products.html.erb` in `/app/views/spree/shared/`? If so, could we see it?

Comment: `def show
      @taxon = Taxon.friendly.find(params[:id])
      return unless @taxon

      @searcher = build_searcher(params.merge(taxon: @taxon.id, include_images: true))
      @products = @searcher.retrieve_products
      @taxonomies = Spree::Taxonomy.includes(root: :children)
    end`

Comment: You should `binding.pry` before the `@products` part and see if it returns something, cause I suspect it to be empty.

Answer (score -1):

Actually I am looking for an answer to "No products found"
Here is my question link:
Spree Commerce: No Products Found 
[Spree Commerce: No Products Found](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46028566/8556206?sem=2)

I have just joined stackoverflow.com a couple of minutes, can't add a comment to above answers.

Here is /controllers/spree/taxons_controller.rb:

```
module Spree
```

class TaxonsController < Spree::StoreController
    rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :render_404
    helper 'spree/products'

```
respond_to :html

def show
  @taxon = Taxon.friendly.find(params[:id])
  return unless @taxon

  @searcher = build_searcher(params.merge(taxon: @taxon.id, include_images: true))

  sorting_scope = params[:order].try(:to_sym) || :ascend_by_updated_at

  @taxonomies = Spree::Taxonomy.includes(root: :children)

  @searcher.retrieve_products

  @products = @searcher.retrieve_products



  @curr_page = params[:page] || 1
  @products_per_page = Spree::Config.products_per_page

  @start_no = @curr_page == 1 ? 1 : ((@curr_page.to_i-1)*@products_per_page)+1

  @end_no = @products.length

  if @curr_page.to_i > 1
     @end_no = ( (@curr_page.to_i-1)*@products_per_page) + @end_no
  end

 # @end_no = @product_count <= @product_count ? @product_count : @products.length+(@curr_page.to_i-1)*@products_per_page

end

private

def accurate_title
  @taxon.try(:seo_title) || super
end
```

end
end