# Spree Commerce: No Products Found

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, spree

my store ypill.com, which had run about three months, run into "no products found" today. I did not change any app code. I went to storefront and search some product where I added it, spree threw an error "no products found. Taxonomies are displaying, but "no products found" anywhere.
ruby 2.3.0;
rails 5.0.2
spree 3.2.1

Answer (score 0):

I tried searching for keyword `body` I got the desired results.

Try this [url](http://ypill.com/products?utf8=%E2%9C%93&email=&taxon=12&keywords=Foot)

Please be specific about your issue and provide the keywords for which it's not working